# Фразеологизмы и придаточные предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Почему фразеологизмы не могут образовывать придаточные конструкции и почему фразеологизмы не могут являться обособленным членом предложения?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не очень понял, о том ли говорит Соан, попробую без философии...

> Почему фразеологизмы не могут образовывать придаточные конструкции

Потому, что нужен присоединяющий (тут - подчинительный) союз. Но это относится не к только к фразеологизмам. Ни одно предложение не может стать подчининенным без соответствующего союза, хотя бы подразумеваемого. 
С таким союзом или союзным словом - без проблем:

А он говорит, (что) **воз и ныне там**.

> и почему фразеологизмы не могут являться обособленным членом предложения?

А он, **гусь лапчатый**, утверждает, что фразеологизмы не могут являться обособленным членом.

Не пойдет?

Comment: "А она принесла конфет как кот наплакал".
Так почему же слово "как" в составе фразеологизма не может выступать в качестве подчинительного союза? В разговорной речи оно часто опускается. Принесла конфет (сколько?) как кот наплакал. Фразеологизм выполняет функцию одного члена предложения- обстоятельства. Только вот непонятно, почему "как" тесно примыкает к самому фразеологизму.

Comment: >"А она принесла конфет как кот наплакал".  
Нет, Максим Шклен., здесь-то как раз не получится. "Как" нельзя оторвать от остальной части фразеологизма. При таком отрыве оставшаяся часть перестанет быть фразеологизмом и станет обычным предложением без ясно выраженной мысли "мало". "Конфет кот наплакал" - это про то, что кот плачет конфетами.

Вот еще более наглядный пример: "пишет как курица лапой" - некрасиво. 
"Пишет курица лапой"  - утверждение, чем именно курица пишет.

Answer (score 1):

Как известно, фразеологизм употребляется как некоторое целое, не подлежащее дальнейшему разложению и обычно не допускающее внутри себя перестановки. А по нормам русского правописания цельные по смыслу выражения перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом  не выделяются знаками препинания, например: Он дойдет *Бог знает до чего* со своими играми (Паустовский). Данное правило основано на том, что фразеологические обороты (к примеру, *делай что хочешь, бери что нравится, спасайся кто может* и т. д.) не образуют придаточного предложения и, как правило, эквивалентны члену предложения. Так, в сочетании *говорит об этом где только может* последние слова имеют значение «везде». Если же какое-либо из приведенных выше и аналогичных сочетаний употреблено не в качестве фразеологического оборота, то оно может образовать придаточное предложение (часто неполное) и выделяться запятыми. Ср.: *Просторечные слова стали употреблять где нужно и где не нужно* (т.е. везде). – *Поставить, где нужно, недостающие знаки препинания* (т.е. там, где нужно).

Comment: >А по нормам русского правописания цельные по смыслу выражения   
  
Правописание тут причем? Вопрос чисто грамматический. Или Вы считаете, что правописание влияет на синтаксис, а не наоборот?

Спрашиваю Вас, поскольку ссылок на источник Вы опять не даете.